# log4j2 + programmatically override a parent custom ConfigurationFactory in a web app

Tags: java, configuration, overriding, log4j2

We are trying something new and posting the question here to see if it is possible.

**TL;DR** Overriding a parent custom ConfigurationFactory in a web app.

**Scenario**: We have bunch of web applications. Some of those web applications write the logs to same log file and other web applications to application related individual log files. So I have written a CustomLoggerConfigFactory (let's call this as parent configuration for the sake of discussion) and bundled that up in a **custom-logger-util.jar** and using this jar as a dependency in the web applications and the logger is getting initialized during web app startup. This configuration has a RollingFileAppender after initialized writes the logs to a file named: ***common-logs.log*** which is working fine. Here below is the code for CustomLoggerConfigFactory.

**Problem**:
Now my question is, say in a web application B, also where the **common-logger-util.jar** is used as a dependency - *how can I extend the CustomLoggerConfigFactory to override the RollingFileAppender **to write the logs to appB.log file instead of common-logs.log** programmatically and without using config files and keeping the rest of the configuration the same i.e. to use the Console appender, Loggers(including RootLogger) as defined by parent config factory?* Can anyone please explain how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
package org.custom.logger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;

import java.net.URI;

@Plugin(name = "CustomLogConfig", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
public class CustomLoggerConfigFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

    static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        //Set the Logger configuration
        builder.setConfigurationName(name);
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.TRACE);

        System.out.println("Testing Logger programmatic configuration");
        String region = System.getProperty(CustomLoggerConstants.LOG4J2_ENV);
        System.out.println("ENV|" + region);

        //Create a pattern layout (common for console and rolling file appenders)
        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", CustomLoggerConstants.KP_STD_CONVERSIONPATTERN);

        FilterComponentBuilder thresholdFilter = builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                .addAttribute("level", getLogLevel(region));

        //Create a Console appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender(CustomLoggerConstants.LOG_TO_CONSOLE, "CONSOLE")
                                                .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(layoutBuilder).addAttribute("pattern", CustomLoggerConstants.KP_STD_CONVERSIONPATTERN);
        appenderBuilder.add(thresholdFilter);
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        //Create a policy for adding it to rolling file appender
        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
                .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "5M"));

        //Create a rolling file appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder rollingFileAppender = builder.newAppender(CustomLoggerConstants.LOG_TO_ROLLING_FILE, "RollingFile")
                .addAttribute("fileName", CustomLoggerConstants.FILENAME + CustomLoggerConstants.FILE_EXTN)
                .addAttribute("filePattern", CustomLoggerConstants.FILENAME + "-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz")
                .add(layoutBuilder)
                .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
        builder.add(rollingFileAppender);

        //Create a logger
        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.kp", getLogLevel(region))
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef(CustomLoggerConstants.LOG_TO_ROLLING_FILE))
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef(CustomLoggerConstants.LOG_TO_CONSOLE))
                .addAttribute("additivity", false)
        );

        //Create root logger
        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO)
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef(CustomLoggerConstants.LOG_TO_CONSOLE))
        );

        System.out.println("Logger programmatic configuration is almost done and ready to be initialized.");
        return builder.build();
        //LoggerContext context = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[]{"*"};
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource configurationSource) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, configurationSource.toString(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(LoggerContext loggerContext, String name, URI configLocation) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
        return createConfiguration(name, builder);
    }

    private static Level getLogLevel(String region) {
        switch (region) {
            case CustomLoggerConstants.DEV:
                return Level.DEBUG;
            case CustomLoggerConstants.QA:
            case CustomLoggerConstants.LOAD:
            case CustomLoggerConstants.PREV:
                return Level.INFO;
            
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have designed my custom config factory and see that as one way to accomplish this.

Here below is the solution.
[image]

The solution is built on Java 8. The interfaces in Java 8 now allow you to define default implementation for the methods and use them. The log4j2 provided `ConfigurationFactory` is already an abstract class but I wanted to separate the creation of configuration and to the individual components having the default implementation.

The `LoggerConfigFactory` in the below image is the custom default implementation that can be used in any of the other apps just by including it (however, in my case, I packaged CustomConfigBuilder, LoggerConfigFactory and LoggerConstants in a jar file).

In the event in the application if any or all of the individual components needs to be defined, all it is required is to create config factory class (AppSpecificLoggerConfigFactory) that extends the default LoggerConfigFactory.

This worked!! Here below is the code for the sake of reference.

```
package org.custom.logger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;


public interface CustomConfigBuilder {

    default Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder, String filename) {
        //Set the Logger configuration
        setLogConfig(name, builder);

        System.out.println("Testing Logger programmatic configuration for " + name);
        String region = System.getProperty(LoggerConstants.LOG4J2_ENV, "PROD");
        System.out.println("ENV from properties file|" + region);
        /*String region = System.getProperty(LoggerConstants.LOG4J2_ENV);
        if(null == region || region.equals("")){
            region = LoggerConstants.PROD;
        }
        System.out.println("ENV from sys props|" + region);*/
        //Create a pattern layout (common for console and rolling file appenders)
        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = createLayoutBuilder(builder);
        FilterComponentBuilder thresholdFilter = createThresholdFilter(builder, region);

        //Create a Console appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender(LoggerConstants.LOG_TO_CONSOLE, "CONSOLE")
                .addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(layoutBuilder).addAttribute("pattern", LoggerConstants.CONVERSIONPATTERN);
        appenderBuilder.add(thresholdFilter);
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        //Create a policy for adding it to rolling file appender
        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = createTriggeringPolicy(builder);

        //Create a rolling file appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder rollingFileAppender = createRollingFileAppender(builder, layoutBuilder, triggeringPolicy, filename);
        builder.add(rollingFileAppender);

        LoggerComponentBuilder appLogger = createAppLogger(builder, region);
        //Create a logger
        builder.add(appLogger);

        //Create root logger
        RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger = createRootLogger(builder);
        builder.add(rootLogger);

        System.out.println("Logger programmatic configuration for " + name + " is almost done and ready to be initialized.");
        return builder.build();
        //LoggerContext context = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    }

    default void setLogConfig(String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        builder.setConfigurationName(name);
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.TRACE);
    }

    default LayoutComponentBuilder createLayoutBuilder(ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", LoggerConstants.CONVERSIONPATTERN);
        return layoutBuilder;
    }

    default FilterComponentBuilder createThresholdFilter(ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder, String region) {
        FilterComponentBuilder thresholdFilter = builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                .addAttribute("level", getLogLevel(region));
        return thresholdFilter;
    }
    default ComponentBuilder createTriggeringPolicy(ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
                .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "5M"));
        return triggeringPolicy;
    }
    default AppenderComponentBuilder createRollingFileAppender(ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder, LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder, ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy, String filename) {
        System.out.println("Filename|" + filename);
        AppenderComponentBuilder rollingFileAppender = builder.newAppender(LoggerConstants.LOG_TO_ROLLING_FILE, "RollingFile")
                .addAttribute("fileName", filename + LoggerConstants.FILE_EXTN)
                .addAttribute("filePattern", filename + "-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz")
                .add(layoutBuilder)
                .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
        return rollingFileAppender;
    }

    default LoggerComponentBuilder createAppLogger(ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder, String region) {
        return builder.newLogger("org.app", getLogLevel(region))
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef(LoggerConstants.LOG_TO_ROLLING_FILE))
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef(LoggerConstants.LOG_TO_CONSOLE))
                .addAttribute("additivity", false);
    }

    default RootLoggerComponentBuilder createRootLogger(ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        return builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO)
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef(LoggerConstants.LOG_TO_CONSOLE));
    }

    default Level getLogLevel(String region) {
        switch (region) {
            case LoggerConstants.DEV:
                return Level.DEBUG;
            case LoggerConstants.QA:
            case LoggerConstants.LOAD:
            case LoggerConstants.PREV:
                return Level.INFO;
            case LoggerConstants.PROD:
                return Level.ERROR;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.custom.logger;

public class LoggerConstants {
    public static final String CONVERSIONPATTERN = "%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c{3} - %m%n";
    public static final String FILENAME = "/logs/logfile";
    public static final String FILE_EXTN = ".log";
    public static final String LOG_TO_ROLLING_FILE = "LogToRollingFile";
    public static final String LOG_TO_CONSOLE = "LogToConsole";
    //public static final String LOG4J2_ENV = "LOG4J2_ENV";
    public static final String LOG4J2_ENV = "log4j2.env";

    public static final String DEV = "DEV";
    public static final String QA = "QA";
    public static final String LOAD = "LOAD";
    public static final String PREV = "PREV";
    public static final String PROD = "PROD";

}
```

---

```
package org.custom.logger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;

import java.net.URI;

@Plugin(name = "CustomLogConfig", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
public class LoggerConfigFactory extends ConfigurationFactory implements CustomConfigBuilder {

    public Configuration createConfiguration(String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        System.out.println("Invoking  default config factory");
        createConfiguration(name, builder, LoggerConstants.FILENAME);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[]{"*"};
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource configurationSource) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, configurationSource.toString(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(LoggerContext loggerContext, String name, URI configLocation) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
        return createConfiguration(name, builder);
    }

}
```

---

All the above three are packaged into one jar file. If the application wants to use the default configuration as defined in the LoggerConfigFactory, all is needed to include this jar file in the app classpath or if it is a web-app then in its WEB-INF/lib.

e.g. in case if the app wants to have its own log file with a different filename, then you would need to extend it. See code below. Note, please make sure to have higher value for the @Order annotation than the value defined in the default config factory.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Order;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.custom.logger.LoggerConfigFactory;

@Plugin(name = "AppCustomLogConfig", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(55)
public class AppSpecificLoggerConfigFactory extends LoggerConfigFactory {

    String filename = "/logs/appSpecificLogFilename";
    @Override
    public Configuration createConfiguration(String name, ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder) {
        System.out.println("Invoking App Specific config factory");
        return createConfiguration(name, builder, filename);
    }
}
```